# Using HMM for speech synthesis

Tags: algorithms, python

I am trying to make a speech synthesizer using a Hidden Markov Model. I read [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis#HMM-based_synthesis) and several whitepapers and presentations ([such as this one](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/ckiw/rpml/HMM_speech_synthesis.pdf)) but I am still not sure how this algorithm can be used to generate waveforms. Can someone explain to me how the algorithm can be applied to this problem?

Comment: The question is very broad. If you have read several articles on the subject, surely you must have been exposed to the main ideas. Which parts do you have trouble understanding?

Comment: @eriatarka84 I'm just unclear on what to set for my states and observations